# error in writing class file to csv

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, idno, leavetaken, leavereqd, reason):
        self.name = name
        self.idno = idno
        self.leavetaken = leavetaken
        self.leavereqd = leavereqd
        self.reason = reason

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}\nID No:{}\nLeave Taken: {}\nLeave Requested: {}\nLeave Reason: {}\n".format(self.name, self.idno, self.leavetaken, self.leavereqd, self.reason)

n = int(raw_input("Please enter the number of employees: "))
employees = []

for i in range(n):
    employee = Employee(
        raw_input("Employee name: "),
        raw_input("Employee ID no: "),
        raw_input("Employee leave taken: ") ,

    raw_input("Employee leave requested: ") ,
        raw_input("Employee leave reason: ") 
    )
    employees.append(employee)

print("\n")

for employee in employees:
    print(employee)
```

I couldn't save the output yo a csv file. It would be a great help if u could help me.

If I try the following to write a csv, I'm getting **key error as zero**.

```
keys = my_li[0].keys()
with open('people.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(my_li)
```

I have tried another way to write them as csv

```
keys = employee[0].keys()
with open('peo.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(employee)
```

and the error I'm getting is

> `AttributeError: Employee instance has no attribute 'getitem'`

`Listwriter` function wasn't successful too. Can anyone get me the solution to write them as csv?

Comment: Oops. While trying to indent, i gave codes and it has created > signs all over my code.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be dict_writer.writerows(employee[0])?

Comment: getting error in keys=employee[0].keys() that employee instance has no attribute getitem

Comment: That's because `employee` is a class instance. You can't do `employee[0]`. It's not a dictionary or a list.

Comment: Then whats the solution to write the above py file as csv? :(

Comment: Is there a reason for each employee to be a class? Can you do with a list of dictionaries, each one representing an employee?

Comment: I want this employee management to be coded using class and i need to get user inputs and the output should be saved as csv

Comment: `employee[0].keys()` shouldn't this be `employees[0].keys()`? This is the reason for the attribute error since, employee is just a class and not a list!

Comment: What are `my_li` and `employee`  in your second and third snippets ???

Comment: employees[0] is a class instance. Doesn't have `keys()` either.

Comment: You would like to see a csv where each column is a name of an employee and each row is one of its properties or vice versa?

Comment: row should have name,id,leave taken,reqd,reason and column should have user defined inputs

Comment: to be more clear, im trying to make a copy of the accessing attributes program in this link but with few more columns, getting user input and writing it to csv  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
columns = ['name', 'idno', 'leavetaken', 'leavereqd', 'reason']
with open('peo.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, columns)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerow({'name': employee.name, 'idno': employee.idno, ...})
```

Iterate through all employees in the list.

Comment: python output shows details of 2 employees when i give n=2 but csv shows only the last one.Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: This implementation uses `writerow` which write a single row-like object (a dict). So everytime you open the file it will just write that row. You can use `writerows([dictionaries])` instead which will write all employees.

Comment: I'm getting errors while trying to write dict in writerows. Can u explain it?

Comment: If i give n=2 as the number of employees, im getting details of 2 employees in python shell but only the last employee details gets printed in csv file

Comment: I'm not getting any error codes. Only the last row of employee data gets printed in csv. eg: if i give n=3, in python shell I'm getting output of 3 employees but in csv I'm getting output of 3rd employee only